# Buildozer process failed executing the last command error while debugging for android

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I have made a simple kivy app using also the socket module. But when I try to convert it to an android app using google collab and buildozer, I am getting this kind of an error.

```
{
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement socket (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for socket


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=starstocksapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,socket,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.5.39'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     HOSTNAME = '047d4a118941'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=\\"172.28.0.2\\""],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.7.8'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '53'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'True'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20211007'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '0'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.1.1'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.1 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=440,driver<441 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
#     COLAB_GPU = '0'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/opt/bin'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
}
```

I don't know why this error keeps on coming. I have my main.py in the directory and I have checked to install all the modules. But still nothing happens.

I think socket module is not included or some problem is due to that I am including socket module. I have written the socket module's name in the spec file also in the modules to be included.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Buildozer.spec would be helpful. Please post your buildozer.spec

Comment: Please, post full log

Comment: I think that you should not add socket to requirements as you have already added python3(socket is inside python3).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add socket in requirements of your buildozer.spec file as they are inbuild modules in python. So, they will automatically get added when you add python3 in your requirements.

See this post for more info:
[Buildozer not using correct kivy version when packaging for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524613/buildozer-not-using-correct-kivy-version-when-packaging-for-android)